# syntastic C++14 support

Tags: filetype-c++, plugin-syntastic

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158772/how-to-add-c11-support-to-syntastic-vim-plugin) using instead of C++11 C++14, but it doesn't work, I still get for this line:

> auto number(0);

that:

> 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98

with syntastic.

Why is syntastic still using C++98 and not C++14?

Comment: Which version of clang do you have? According to [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) you need at least version 3.4 for `-std=c++14` to work. For earlier versions, you need to use `-std=c++1y` (invalid values for `-std` seem to be ignored).

Comment: Do you also have YCM installed?

Comment: I have clang 3.6 installed, thus it should work :·)

Comment: Yes, I have YCM installed. Are there any incompatibilities with it?

Comment: Because YCM disables syntastic checks by default.  With recent versions of syntastic the `:SyntasticInfo` command will tell you that (provided that you run in against a C++ file).

Comment: According to [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500281/youcompleteme-and-syntastic-compatibility), YCM is checking the file. Am I right?

Comment: Try `:help syntastic-ycm` for a shorter version.  But basically, yes, if you didn't set `g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui` to 0, it's YCM that checks the file.

Comment: Thank you  lcd047! Now that I added "let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0" to my .vimrc, I have syntastic checking it! But it is talking about C++11 and not 14!: " 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions] [cpp/clang_check] "

Comment: What does this label tell you: `[cpp/clang_check]`? :)

Comment: Most issues with syntastic are actually issues with the checker used by syntastic, not with syntastic itself. Read your checker's documentation or find another checker that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Ok, I understood what [cpp/clang_check] is! :·)
ok! Let's configure clang-check! " cpp/clang_check " points to " c/clang_check ". And at this point, I'm a bit lost. Is clang-check the same as clang, or a sub-part or anything else? I can't find how to configure it. Should I configure it directly or configure how Syntastic uses it?

Comment: Please consider reading the docs before you read the sources.  Start with `:help syntastic`, skim through the [FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic#faq), then read the docs for the relevant [checkers](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Syntax-Checkers).  `clang-check` is a separate program (part of the CLANG project, but not the same as the compiler), and it has its own checker in syntastic.  You can read about it [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C--%3A---clang_check).  But really, carefully reading the docs can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Actually, I did check the documentation, but did not understand how to add "-std=c++14" to it. And now I just realized that what I want to do is to add an argument, thus " let g:syntastic_cpp_clang_check_post_args = "-std=c++14" " ! And it works just fine! Thank you all!

Comment: The point is, in order to know __where__ to add it you really have to understand what syntastic is doing.  There is no such thing as telling syntastic "use `--std=c++14` for C++".  The interface is downright barbaric, and it's way more complicated than it should be.  There are other serious problems with it too, f.i. not being able to infer compilation flags from makefiles.  But it's the best I could come up with given Vim's API. :(

Answer (score 4):

In my .vimrc, I have:

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['gcc']
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'gcc'
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = '-std=c++14'
```

And, if you have YCM enabled:

```
let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0
```

And now it works!

Comment: Note that you're using gcc now, and not clang (clang has much better errors).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: He's actually using `clang-check`, which is essentially the same as clang's parser.  On a side note, `clang-tidy` is interesting too.

Comment: I am really sorry but I have to change my answer, because, as I came back to Vim and typed in something that would cause an error, I realized that actually, syntastic does NOT CORRECT AT ALL! Thats why it did not give anything about 'auto'.

I know that it is only bypassing this problem, but by using gcc as syntastic checker and compiler, it works just fine! (really, this time!).